# Virtualenv requirement already satisfied

Tags: pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to use the simple command `virtualenv .`, but it says virtualenv does not exist. However, when I try `pip install virtualenv` or `sudo pip install virtualenv`, it says the "Requirement already satisfied". I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is output of ``pip list | grep virtualenv``?

Comment: virtualenv (15.0.3)

Comment: How about ``which virtualenv``? Have you tried to run it manually?

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean? I ran `which virtualenv` but didn't receive any output.

Comment: Utility ``which`` shows you where the binary for the command actually is. No output means that ``virtualenv`` is not in you ``PATH`` (if yout using linux). Therefore try to find it manually (``find / -name virtualenv``).